# DJANGO - NoReverseMatch at /create/

Tags: python, django, web, cs50

I am fairly new to Django and for my certification, I am working on cloning Wikipedia. I was able to get the wiki and editing commands to work but having difficulties creating new entries. This is my function to create a new entry:
** Main urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("encyclopedia.urls"))
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path ("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path ("edit/<str:title>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path ("create/<str:title>", views.create, name="create")
]
```

**views.py**

```
class Post(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label= "Title")
    textarea = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(), label='')
```

```
def create(request, title):
    if request.method == "POST": 
        form = Post(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            textarea = form.cleaned_data['textarea']
            entries : util.list_entries()

            if title in entries: 
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
                "form": Search(), 
                "message": "Page already exists", 
                "type": "exists"
                })

            else: 
                util.save_entry(title,textarea)
                page=util.get_entry(title)
                page_converted = md.convert(page)
                return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {
                    "form": Search(), 
                    'page': page_converted, 
                    "title": title
                    })
    else: 
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {
            "form": Search(), 
            "post": Post()
            
            })
```

**MY TEMPLATE**
**Creating a new entry**

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Create
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'create' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h4 class="display-2">Create new page:</h4>
        <h6 class="post-title">Title: {{post.title}}</h6>
            {{post.textarea}}
        <br>
        <input class="save btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**Pop an error if the page already exists/not found**

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Error
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<h1 class="display-2 error">{{message}}</h1>

{% if type == "not_found" %}
<h3>The page {{title}} cannot be found.</h3>
{% endif %}
{% if type == "exists" %}
 <h3>The page {{title}} already exists.</h3>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**THE ERROR THAT DJANGO RETURNS**

```
NoReverseMatch at /create/HTML
Reverse for 'create' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create/(?P<title>[^/]+)$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/create/HTML
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'create' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['create/(?P<title>[^/]+)$']
Exception Location: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.6
Python Path:    
['/Users/amertoukan/Desktop/Projects/cs50/Django/wiki',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/amertoukan/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you sm in advance.

Comment: could you also show your urls.py?

Comment: Hello, I've edited my question to include the urls.py but here it is: ```from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path ("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path ("edit/<str:title>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path ("create/<str:title>", views.create, name="create")
]
```

Comment: and your main urls.py?

Comment: ```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("encyclopedia.urls"))
]
```
I will also be adding it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that when you create a new entry, you do not have `title` yet.

You are getting the title and save it to edit it later.

```
path ("create/", views.create, name="create")
```

and in views.py

```
def create(request): # no title.
```